# Fargate how to select x86/arm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using fargate with elastic container service.

I see there are pricing of both x86 and arm for fargate so I assume that I would be able to choose between x86 and arm when I am creating a service with launch type fargate.

But I couldn't find an option to choose between x86 / arm when I am creating a service with launch type fargate. What I can see from the console is ability to select operating system (Linux, Window Sever 2019 Full and Window Server 2019 core)

How can I choose between launching fargate with x86 or arm?

Answer (score 2):

There are screenshots of the ECS console on the official blog.

[Announcing AWS Graviton2 Support for AWS Fargate – Get up to 40% Better Price-Performance for Your Serverless Containers | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-graviton2-support-for-aws-fargate-get-up-to-40-better-price-performance-for-your-serverless-containers/)